# cuDNN Status Not Supported when trying to use FFT Convolution

Tags: cuda, fft, convolution, cudnn

I am trying to use the cuDNN library to do a FFT convolution. The code runs when I use the Winograd convolution / the cuDNN method that selects the fastest convolution method, but when I tried to run using the FFT convolution method it does not work.

I set the forward method to FFT convolution myself.

I checked the documents and my input is in NCHW format as required for the FFT convolution. From the docs:

```
CUDNN_CONVOLUTION_FWD_ALGO_FFT
xDesc Format Support: NCHW HW-packed
yDesc Format Support: NCHW HW-packed
```

The error "CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED" happens during the cudnnGetConvolutionForwardWorkspaceSize function call.

What is happening that causes this error when I use FFT convolution VS best or Winograd?

For reference I am using cuda 9.1, cuDNN 7. I compile with the following command on Ubuntu 16.04: nvcc -arch=sm_35 -std=c++11 -O2 -lcudnn FFT_cuDNN.cu -o conv `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`; ./conv TF.png

```
#include <cudnn.h>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/dnn.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace cv::dnn;

#define checkCUDNN(expression)                               \
  {                                                          \
    cudnnStatus_t status = (expression);                     \
    if (status != CUDNN_STATUS_SUCCESS) {                    \
      std::cerr << "Error on line " << __LINE__ << ": "      \
                << cudnnGetErrorString(status) << std::endl; \
      std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                               \
    }                                                        \
  }

cv::Mat load_image_NCHW(const char* image_path)
{
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread(image_path, cv::IMREAD_COLOR);
    image.convertTo(image, CV_32FC3);
    cv::normalize(image,image,0,1, cv::NORM_MINMAX);

    cv::Mat inputBlob = blobFromImage(image, 1.0f, cv::Size(image.rows,image.cols), cv::Scalar(0,0,0));
    return inputBlob;
}

void save_image(const char* output_filename,
                float* buffer,
                int height,
                int width) {
  cv::Mat output_image(height, width, CV_32FC3, buffer);
  // Make negative values zero.
  cv::threshold(output_image,
                output_image,
                /*threshold=*/0,
                /*maxval=*/0,
                cv::THRESH_TOZERO);
  cv::normalize(output_image, output_image, 0.0, 255.0, cv::NORM_MINMAX);
  output_image.convertTo(output_image, CV_8UC3);
  cv::imwrite(output_filename, output_image);
  std::cerr << "Wrote output to " << output_filename << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
  if (argc < 2) {
    std::cerr << "usage: conv <image> [gpu=0] [sigmoid=0]" << std::endl;
    std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  int gpu_id = (argc > 2) ? std::atoi(argv[2]) : 0;
  std::cerr << "GPU: " << gpu_id << std::endl;

  bool with_sigmoid = (argc > 3) ? std::atoi(argv[3]) : 0;
  std::cerr << "With sigmoid: " << std::boolalpha << with_sigmoid << std::endl;

  // Load the image
  cv::Mat image = load_image_NCHW(argv[1]);

  int imgH = 600;
  int imgW = 561;
  int inC = 3;

  // Set GPU to use
  cudaSetDevice(gpu_id);

  // Create the cudnn Handle
  cudnnHandle_t cudnn;
  checkCUDNN(cudnnCreate(&cudnn));

  // Need a descriptor for
  // The input, kernel, and convolution

  cudnnTensorDescriptor_t input_descriptor;
  checkCUDNN(cudnnCreateTensorDescriptor(&input_descriptor));
  checkCUDNN(cudnnSetTensor4dDescriptor(input_descriptor,
                                        /*format=*/CUDNN_TENSOR_NCHW,
                                        /*dataType=*/CUDNN_DATA_FLOAT,
                                        /*batch_size=*/1,
                                        /*channels=*/inC,
                                        /*image_height=*/imgH,
                                        /*image_width=*/imgW));

  cudnnFilterDescriptor_t kernel_descriptor;
  checkCUDNN(cudnnCreateFilterDescriptor(&kernel_descriptor));
  checkCUDNN(cudnnSetFilter4dDescriptor(kernel_descriptor,
                                        /*dataType=*/CUDNN_DATA_FLOAT,
                                        /*format=*/CUDNN_TENSOR_NCHW,
                                        /*out_channels=*/3,
                                        /*in_channels=*/inC,
                                        /*kernel_height=*/3,
                                        /*kernel_width=*/3));

  cudnnConvolutionDescriptor_t convolution_descriptor;
  checkCUDNN(cudnnCreateConvolutionDescriptor(&convolution_descriptor));
  checkCUDNN(cudnnSetConvolution2dDescriptor(convolution_descriptor,
                                             /*pad_height=*/1,
                                             /*pad_width=*/1,
                                             /*vertical_stride=*/1,
                                             /*horizontal_stride=*/1,
                                             /*dilation_height=*/1,
                                             /*dilation_width=*/1,
                                             /*mode=*/CUDNN_CROSS_CORRELATION,
                                             /*computeType=*/CUDNN_DATA_FLOAT));

  // Need to compute the output size
  int batch_size{0}, channels{0}, height{0}, width{0};
  checkCUDNN(cudnnGetConvolution2dForwardOutputDim(convolution_descriptor,
                                                   input_descriptor,
                                                   kernel_descriptor,
                                                   &batch_size,
                                                   &channels,
                                                   &height,
                                                   &width));

  std::cerr << "Output Image: " << height << " x " << width << " x " << channels
            << std::endl;

  // Need an output descriptor
  cudnnTensorDescriptor_t output_descriptor;
  checkCUDNN(cudnnCreateTensorDescriptor(&output_descriptor));
  checkCUDNN(cudnnSetTensor4dDescriptor(output_descriptor,
                                        /*format=*/CUDNN_TENSOR_NCHW,
                                        /*dataType=*/CUDNN_DATA_FLOAT,
                                        /*batch_size=*/1,
                                        /*channels=*/3,
                                        /*image_height=*/imgH,
                                        /*image_width=*/imgW));

  // Need to define the forward algorithm
  cudnnConvolutionFwdAlgo_t convolution_algorithm = CUDNN_CONVOLUTION_FWD_ALGO_FFT;

  // Have to compute the workspace size
  size_t workspace_bytes{0};
  checkCUDNN(cudnnGetConvolutionForwardWorkspaceSize(cudnn,
                                                     input_descriptor,
                                                     kernel_descriptor,
                                                     convolution_descriptor,
                                                     output_descriptor,
                                                     convolution_algorithm,
                                                     &workspace_bytes));

  std::cerr << "Workspace size: " << (workspace_bytes / 1048576.0) << "MB"
            << std::endl;
  assert(workspace_bytes > 0);

  // Allocate the memory needed for the workspace
  void* d_workspace{nullptr};
  cudaMalloc(&d_workspace, workspace_bytes);

  // Allocate memory for the batch of images
  // and copy from host to device
  int image_bytes = batch_size * channels * height * width * sizeof(float);

  float* d_input{nullptr};
  cudaMalloc(&d_input, image_bytes);
  cudaMemcpy(d_input, image.ptr<float>(0), image_bytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

  // Allocate memory for the output images
  // Copy from host to device
  float* d_output{nullptr};
  cudaMalloc(&d_output, image_bytes);
  cudaMemset(d_output, 0, image_bytes);

  // clang-format off
  const float kernel_template[3][3] = {
    {1, 1, 1},
    {1, -8, 1},
    {1, 1, 1}
  };
  // clang-format on

  float h_kernel[3][3][3][3];
  for (int kernel = 0; kernel < 3; ++kernel) {
    for (int channel = 0; channel < 3; ++channel) {
      for (int row = 0; row < 3; ++row) {
        for (int column = 0; column < 3; ++column) {
          h_kernel[kernel][channel][row][column] = kernel_template[row][column];
        }
      }
    }
  }

  float* d_kernel{nullptr};
  cudaMalloc(&d_kernel, sizeof(h_kernel));
  cudaMemcpy(d_kernel, h_kernel, sizeof(h_kernel), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

  // Perform actual convolution
  const float alpha = 1.0f, beta = 0.0f;

  checkCUDNN(cudnnConvolutionForward(cudnn,
                                     &alpha,
                                     input_descriptor,
                                     d_input,
                                     kernel_descriptor,
                                     d_kernel,
                                     convolution_descriptor,
                                     convolution_algorithm,
                                     d_workspace,
                                     workspace_bytes,
                                     &beta,
                                     output_descriptor,
                                     d_output));

  // If wish to use sigmoid activation
  if (with_sigmoid) {
    cudnnActivationDescriptor_t activation_descriptor;
    checkCUDNN(cudnnCreateActivationDescriptor(&activation_descriptor));
    checkCUDNN(cudnnSetActivationDescriptor(activation_descriptor,
                                            CUDNN_ACTIVATION_SIGMOID,
                                            CUDNN_PROPAGATE_NAN,
                                            /*relu_coef=*/0));
    checkCUDNN(cudnnActivationForward(cudnn,
                                      activation_descriptor,
                                      &alpha,
                                      output_descriptor,
                                      d_output,
                                      &beta,
                                      output_descriptor,
                                      d_output));
    cudnnDestroyActivationDescriptor(activation_descriptor);
  }

  // Move results to host
  float* h_output = new float[image_bytes];
  cudaMemcpy(h_output, d_output, image_bytes, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

  save_image("cudnn-out.png", h_output, height, width);

  // Free memory
  delete[] h_output;
  cudaFree(d_kernel);
  cudaFree(d_input);
  cudaFree(d_output);
  cudaFree(d_workspace);

  cudnnDestroyTensorDescriptor(input_descriptor);
  cudnnDestroyTensorDescriptor(output_descriptor);
  cudnnDestroyFilterDescriptor(kernel_descriptor);
  cudnnDestroyConvolutionDescriptor(convolution_descriptor);

  cudnnDestroy(cudnn);
}
```

Comment: "The combination of the tensor descriptors, filter descriptor and convolution descriptor is not supported for the specified algorithm.". It is possible that the error should be taken at face value and it just isn't supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, from the docs : xDesc's feature map height + 2 * convDesc's zero-padding height must equal 256 or less xDesc's feature map width + 2 * convDesc's zero-padding width must equal 256 or less.

When I initially read it I was under the impression the zero-padding height meant the kernelH-1, when it refers to the total padded image height / width.

My image was too large. If I resize it works i.e:

```
cv::Mat inputBlob = blobFromImage(image, 1.0f, cv::Size(100,100), cv::Scalar(0,0,0));
```